# Reverse of Matrix-Vector Multiplication without using inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let's say I have an invertible square matrix $A\in\mathbb{M}_{n\times{n}}(\mathbb{R})$ and vectors $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $A\vec{x}=\vec{y}$. If I know $A$ and $\vec{y}$, I know I can calculate $\vec{x}$ by performing $\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{y}$.  However, I was wondering if there is a method to find $\vec{x}$ *without* using matrix inverses anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: You have a linear equation system of $n$ variables and $n$ equations. It can be solved by applying the **Gaussian elimination method** or other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), which involves row reduction steps on an augmented matrix $[A\mid\vec y]$. This method works even when $A$ is not invertible. However, in the case that $A$ is not invertible, the vector $x$ need not be unique, and there can be infinitely many solutions or no solutions (if the system is inconsistent).

For example, if $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec y=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$, then $A$ is not invertible and the Gaussian Elimination yields:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&\mid&1\\2&2&\mid&2\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&1&\mid&1\\0&0&\mid&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then from this, we see that $\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+span\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)$, so there are infinitely many solutions to $A\vec x=\vec y$ in this example.

Comment: Thank you. How did you get $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: This is because $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is a vector such that when multiplied by $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ it yields the zero vector. This spanning vector is why there are infinitely many solutions, because any multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ can be added to $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and it will still solve the system, because $A\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\vec 0$.

Comment: Okay. This answer makes a lot of sense. Thanks!